# vertical "justification" of tcolorboxes in a multicol environment

Tags: tcolorbox, multicol, vertical-spacing

I'm making exercice sheets with breakable tcolorboxes and multicols.

When a box breaks, it goes as bottom as possible in its column, which is perfect. However, it's not the case for the boxes who don't break.

I would like a kind of vertical justification that spaces my boxes so that they take the whole vertical space available. In that way, all my last boxes would be aligned at the bottom of the column, broken or not.

Could someone help me do that ?

[image]

A MWE of my code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside=semi, 11pt, DIV=16,listof=entryprefix,headings=openright]{scrbook}



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[most,many,listings,skins]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[autooneside=false]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{multicol}



\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\onehalfspacing


\newcommand{\dum}{This is a sentence of dummy text. }




\setkomafont{disposition}{\bfseries\sffamily}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\automark[chapter]{chapter}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand*{\headfont}{\itshape\sffamily}


\newcounter{compteur}[chapter]


\newtcolorbox[use counter*=compteur]{exo}[1]{varwidth boxed title=15cm,breakable, enhanced, colback=black!0,colframe=black!20,adjusted title=\label{\thecompteur}Exercice \thecompteur #1,coltitle=black,fonttitle=\small\bfseries\sffamily,before skip=0.1cm,attach boxed title to top left={xshift=-0mm,yshift*=-6.22mm},boxed title style={sharp corners=uphill,right=0mm,left=0mm,boxsep=0.5mm,colback=black!20,colframe=black!20},pad at break=1.5mm, break at=-\baselineskip/0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Exercises}
\begin{multicols*}{2}


\begin{exo}{}
 \dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}
\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}{}
\dum\dum\dum\dum
\end{exo}



\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a rule on this site, you should always provide compilable code. Too many things could influence the small sample of code that you showed.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Code provided !

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I doubt that all this code is necessary to highlight the problem. Do what is usually done when debugging code, remove any line that isn't necessary to trigger the problem. It's called a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). It will allow other people to test your code efficiently.

Comment: Done. Thank you again.